# How to pass powershell parameters into Chef

Tags: powershell, chef-infra

For some reason when I pass parameters through the options section it doesn't like my powershell arguments.  I hate to bother you guys, but do you have any ideas what might be the problem?  Thanks in advance!

Essentially all I am trying to do with powershell is this -

`Start-Process -FilePath "T:\QualysCloudAgent.exe" -argumentlist "CustomerId={etc..etc..etc..} ActivationId={etc..etc..etc..}"`

```
when 'windows'
  windows_package 'QualysCloudAgent' do
    source 'T:\QualysCloudAgent.exe'
    options '-argumentlist "CustomerId={etc...etc...etc..} ActivationId={etc...etc..etc...}"'
    installer_type :custom
    action :install
  end
end
```

Comment: separate your args with quotes and commas. "CustomerId={etc...etc...etc..}",  "ActivationId={etc...etc..etc...}". If that does it for you let me know so I can post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not running `powershell.exe` - unless `QualysCloudAgent.exe` accepts an `-ArgumentList` parameter then your executable likely doesn't understand the argument. Just pass your options to the resource like so:

```
options %Q(CustomerId={etc...etc...etc..} ActivationId={etc...etc..etc...})
```

You may also want to consider using a [`guard`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#guards) as well, to make sure idempotency is maintained during convergence (e.g. don't install if it's already installed). For example, in your resource, you might do something like this in your block above, since you have the `:custom` `installer_type` set:

```
not_if %Q(# PowerShell code to check if the program is installed)
guard_interpreter :powershell_script
```

Setting the [`guard_interpreter`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#guard-interpreters) on a resource tells Chef to evaluate a `not_if` or `only_if` string under a resource as that language. See the linked page for the different runtimes Chef supports in this context.

---

Side note: `%Q()` is a shortcut in Ruby for double-quoted string literals, with an added bonus - you don't have to escape double quotes anymore (although you will have to quote unopened closing parentheses, such as `%Q(My name is Bender\()`, but `%Q(My name is (Bender))` does not need to be), which is usually a huge help in building external command arguments, especially in Chef. [This section of the Ruby wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation) explains more about the alternative notations for different literals which you may find useful/graceful in other situations as well.